# How to see if additional columns in SQL are empty?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have semester grades saved in a table. The students take 2 tests per Semester and the course is 4 semesters long (a total of 8 tests). I already checked to see if there are ABSOLUTELY NO GRADES in the table, now that that is through ... how can i check the, preferably last grade given, and echo all the grades up to that point.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM infot WHERE Vorname='".$_SESSION['Fname']."'";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1);

$check1 = mysql_num_rows($res1);
if ($check1 > 0 )
        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
        {
        $note1 = 
        "

        ";
        }
    else
    {
    $nichts1=
    "
    <h2> Info T </h2> <br>
    Es gibt noch keine Noten, bereite dich vor! Klausuren kommen!!
    ";

    echo $nichts1;
    }
```

Pardon the German, i am working from Germany =) But my question is, what exactly do i put in $note1, i mean would i have to do another num_row check or ... what would be the most painless way of doing this?

And please do NOT tell me to check every single grade for NULL ... i know how to do that but it seems like so much unneeded work =)

Comment: Checking for `NULL` is probably less work than asking this question here. ;-) How are the grades stored? Your code and your explanation reveil nothing about your table structure, apart from the existance of a 'Vorname' (first name) field.

Comment: There is a First and Last name field (like you guessed) and then the fields go TEST1, TEST2, SEM1Grade, TEST3, TEST4, SEM2Grade ... and so on until we get to SEM4Grade, which totals 12 entries ... 

Is checking for NULL realy the easiest thing to do ??

Comment: If that is your table structure, then yes. But I would recommend you to read about normalization and move the grade results to a child table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all those fields in a single table, then you need to check if each of them is null. Fortunately, if you want to check if they are *all* null, you can use the `COALESCE` function. It returns the first non-null value of a range of values. So if it returns `null`, it means that every value you passed to it is `null`.

```
select
  *
from
  Students s
where
  COALESCE(TEST1, TEST2, SEM1Grade, TEST3, TEST4, SEM2Grade) IS NULL
```

To select the last grade, you can do a similar thing, by reverting the order of the fields:

```
select
  s.*,
  COALESCE(SEM2Grade, TEST4, TEST3, SEM1Grade, TEST2, TEST1) as LastGrade
from
  Students s
```

If you need more complex operations, you might still need a more verbose query, though.

Comment: YES !! THANK YOU !! That is exactly what i was looking for =) just tested it now, works like a charm =) now to tweek it into the code =)